# How do I specify a rails route that does nothing

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I want to discard some requests and to nothing. Generate no errors.
Rails 4.1.

A route like this:

ActionController::RoutingError (No route matches [GET] "/edist-images/article/bw_2014-mid-year-outlook_180x120.jpg"):

Comment: Why not just delete those routes alltogether?

Comment: Actually, the app is causing those requests to be generated.  In the production environment that is necessary and they are valid.  In development environment, the images are not available, but the requests are still generated.  This adds noise to the errors in the log file.  Messy.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You can force Rails to respond to specific routes with a HTTP status code. For example, to respond with a 200 OK for your missing image:

```
get '/edist-images/article/bw_2014-mid-year-outlook_180x120.jpg', to: proc { [200, {}, ['']] }
```

Comment: Can I use a wildcard for the image name?  It sounds pretty good.

Comment: `get '/edist-images/article/*image', to: proc { [200, {}, ['']] }` would match any routes starting with '/edist-images/article/'. See the route globbing docs for more info http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#route-globbing-and-wildcard-segments